# Check if browser's location turned on Only once

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition function to check if the browser's location is on or not. But this function is getting called more than once (without page load). For example if i switch to another tab and go back to the page's tab it gets called.

My code is

```
<script>

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
   alert("i'm tracking you!");
},

function (error) {
   if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED){
      alert("you denied me :-(");
   }
});

</script>
```

How can i call that function only once?

Comment: set a cookie flag or window session storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of whether the watchPosition function has fired your function or not:

```
var firedAlready = false;

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
   if(!firedAlready) {
      alert("i'm tracking you!");
      firedAlready = true;
   }
},

function (error) {
   if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED){
      alert("you denied me :-(");
   }
});
```

Comment: It won't work, reloading the page will reinitialize the fired already and yuo start again. The data needs to be persistent(read my answer)

Comment: He said its getting re-called without page load, so I answered how to stop it from being re-called without page load. Yes the answer is different if between page loads he doesn't want it to be called again, but he didn't say that.

Comment: you are right, but doing it the right way from start it's better than going step by step (time wise), nevertheless it's good by going from mistake to mistake cause that is the best way to learn. And also, declining tracking and switching tabs will cause another alert, every time if you don't accept it.(Not so user friendly). Purely my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an enclosure for your code! This will make sure it's only performed once.

```
var something = (function() {
    var executed = false;
    return function () {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            // do something
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also consider disabling the event handler with `navigator.geolocation.clearWatch()`.
E.g.:

```
var id;
id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
    alert("i'm tracking you!");
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
},
function (error) {
    if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        alert("you denied me :-(");
        // I suspect this is actually unnecessary since we were denied.
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
    }
});
```

For more details check [the MDN page about Geolocation.clearWatch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/clearWatch).

Answer (score 0):

You can clear position listener when you have already got the result.

[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/clearWatch)

Or you maybe use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostion to test whether is on or off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the status of checking the permission in local storage for long duration use or better use cookies for that site and save the preferences there.

If you only do a variable when the page is reloaded the variable is reinitialized.

Your data need to be persistent.

Start from here if you are new with cookies 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp